# Why is not sake freezing in the freezer but on the air after serving?

Tags: science, sake, cooling

I found interesting video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hFSWTHhVdqE, with pouring sake that freezes in the glass at room temperature. How is it possible? Why it is not possible to make ice crystals while standstill in the freezer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sake was most likely [supercooled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercooling).  It was cooled below its freezing point, but there were no impurities to form ice crystals.  When it was poured into a glass, as the author of that video suggests in his comment, it created turbulence that produced ice crystals to form, and once that process starts, accelerates until it is completely frozen.  It is a fun experiment [to do yourself with just water](https://www.popsci.com/supercooling-instant-slushies).